# Android Studio CMake Error: Build Command failed fasttext

Tags: java, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk, clang++

I am trying to consume Native code (C++) in Android using NDK. I get a build failure when I am trying to make the project. The c++ code has been taken from https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/tree/master/src. It's added to the following location C:\Users\xxx\AndroidStudioProjects\blah\app\src\main\cpp.

Contents of my CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project(fasttext)

# The version number.
set (fasttext_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set (fasttext_VERSION_MINOR 1)

include_directories(fasttext)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -pthread -std=c++11 -funroll-loops -O3 -march=native")

set(HEADER_FILES
    src/main/cpp/args.h
    src/main/cpp/densematrix.h
    src/main/cpp/dictionary.h
    src/main/cpp/fasttext.h
    src/main/cpp/loss.h
    src/main/cpp/matrix.h
    src/main/cpp/meter.h
    src/main/cpp/model.h
    src/main/cpp/productquantizer.h
    src/main/cpp/quantmatrix.h
    src/main/cpp/real.h
    src/main/cpp/utils.h
    src/main/cpp/vector.h)

set(SOURCE_FILES
    src/main/cpp/args.cc
    src/main/cpp/densematrix.cc
    src/main/cpp/dictionary.cc
    src/main/cpp/fasttext.cc
    src/main/cpp/loss.cc
    src/main/cpp/main.cc
    src/main/cpp/matrix.cc
    src/main/cpp/meter.cc
    src/main/cpp/model.cc
    src/main/cpp/productquantizer.cc
    src/main/cpp/quantmatrix.cc
    src/main/cpp/utils.cc
    src/main/cpp/vector.cc)

add_library(fasttext-shared SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
add_library(fasttext-static STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
add_library(fasttext-static_pic STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
set_target_properties(fasttext-shared PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME fasttext)
set_target_properties(fasttext-static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME fasttext)
set_target_properties(fasttext-static_pic PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME fasttext_pic POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE True)
add_executable(fasttext-bin src/main/cpp/main.cc)
target_link_libraries(fasttext-bin pthread fasttext-static)
set_target_properties(fasttext-bin PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER 
"${HEADER_FILES}" OUTPUT_NAME fasttext)
install (TARGETS fasttext-shared
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
install (TARGETS fasttext-static
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
install (TARGETS fasttext-static_pic
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
install (TARGETS fasttext-bin
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include/fasttext)
```

Failure message:

```
 Build command failed.
 Error while executing process 
 C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe 
 with arguments {--build C:\Users\xxx\AndroidStudioProjects\blah\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\x86_64 --target fasttext-bin}
 [1/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fasttext-static.dir/src/main/cpp/model.cc.o
 [2/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fasttext-static.dir/src/main/cpp/fasttext.cc.o
 [3/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fasttext-static.dir/src/main/cpp/args.cc.o
 [4/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fasttext-static.dir/src/main/cpp/dictionary.cc.o
 [5/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fasttext-static.dir/src/main/cpp/densematrix.cc.o
 [6/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fasttext-static.dir/src/main/cpp/loss.cc.o
 [7/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fasttext-static.dir/src/main/cpp/matrix.cc.o
 [8/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fasttext-static.dir/src/main/cpp/meter.cc.o
 [9/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fasttext-static.dir/src/main/cpp/main.cc.o
 [10/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fasttext-static.dir/src/main/cpp/utils.cc.o
 [11/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fasttext-static.dir/src/main/cpp/vector.cc.o
 [12/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fasttext-static.dir/src/main/cpp/productquantizer.cc.o
 [13/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fasttext-static.dir/src/main/cpp/quantmatrix.cc.o C:\Users\xxx\AndroidStudioProjects\blah\app\src\main\cpp\fasttext.cc:323:16: warning: 'selectEmbeddings' is deprecated: selectEmbeddings is being deprecated. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

 auto idx = selectEmbeddings(qargs.cutoff);

           ^ 

 C:\Users\xxx\AndroidStudioProjects\blah\app\src\main\cpp/utils.h:18: 
 49: note: expanded from macro 'FASTTEXT_DEPRECATED'

 #define FASTTEXT_DEPRECATED(msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__(msg)))

 C:\Users\xxx\AndroidStudioProjects\blah\app\src\main\cpp\fasttext.cc:551
 :5: warning: 'precomputeWordVectors' is deprecated: 
 precomputeWordVectors is being deprecated. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

precomputeWordVectors(*wordVectors_);

^

C:\Users\xxx\AndroidStudioProjects\blah\app\src\main\cpp/fasttext.h:180:
3: note: 'precomputeWordVectors' has been explicitly marked deprecated 
here

FASTTEXT_DEPRECATED("precomputeWordVectors is being deprecated.")

^

C:\Users\xxx\AndroidStudioProjects\blah\app\src\main\cpp/utils.h:18:49: 
note: expanded from macro 'FASTTEXT_DEPRECATED'

#define FASTTEXT_DEPRECATED(msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__(msg)))

2 warnings generated.

[14/16] Linking CXX static library libfasttext.a
[15/16] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fasttext- 
bin.dir/src/main/cpp/main.cc.o
[16/16] Linking CXX executable fasttext
FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk- 
bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  -- 
target=x86_64-none-linux-android21 --gcc- 
toolchain=C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk- 
bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 -- 
sysroot=C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk- 
bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot  -pthread - 
std=c++11 -funroll-loops -O3 -march=native -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  - 
Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static- 
libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings - 
Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--gc-sections 
CMakeFiles/fasttext-bin.dir/src/main/cpp/main.cc.o  -o fasttext  - 
lpthread libfasttext.a -latomic -lm && cd ."
C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk- 
bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux- 
android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin\ld: error: cannot find 
-lpthread

clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Appreciate much in advance any tips/suggestions on why I am getting this error. 
Thanks!

Comment: You got the error message `error: cannot find -lpthread`. This is because Android implements POSIX threads functionality *internally* and **doesn't have** separate `pthread` library for it. It is better to use `pthread` library in CMake via `find_package(Threads)`, which works for Android too.

Comment: Thanks much Tsyvarev! Is there a disadvantage to altogether removing "-pthread" and "-march=native" options when setting my CMake C compiler flags?